# Python Snake Game Boundries not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm new to python and I'm trying following along with a tutorial that uses PyGame to create a snake like game. For some reason my boundaries are not working. It may be something simple but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. I don't get any errors, the snake just goes past the boundaries and the game doesn't end.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')




clock = pygame.time.Clock()
block_size = 10
FPS = 30

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])


def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    lead_x = display_width/2
    lead_y = display_height/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0

    randAppleX = random.randrange (0, display_width-block_size)
    randAppleY = random.randrange (0, display_height-block_size)

    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Game over, press C to play again or Q to quit", red)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lead_x_change = -block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lead_x_change = block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    lead_y_change = -block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    lead_y_change = block_size
                    lead_X_change = 0

        **if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:
            gameOver == True #boundaries**






        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [randAppleX, randAppleY, block_size, block_size])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x , lead_y, block_size, block_size])
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS) 


    message_to_screen("You Lose", red)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 3):

In your exit condition, you're using the equality comparison, not the assignment operator:

```
    if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:
        gameOver == True #boundaries
```

in the above,

```
gameOver == True
```

should be

```
gameOver = True
```